# ERROR ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, extract, to-date

I am trying to execute the following sql statement for an oracle database:

```
UPDATE PARENT
SET RENEW_DATE = TO_DATE('08/31/' + EXTRACT(YEAR FROM JOINED), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
WHERE STATUS_IND = 'Active';
```

I am expecting to get the year piece from the field called Joined which is a date formatted like MM/dd/yyyy. I want the end result, or the value I am setting to look like '8/31/2015' for example.

Any help is appreciated I have tried multiple things.

Comment: What datatype is `JOINED`?

Comment: I apologize, what I was getting before is the ORA-00932, with the above I am getting ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: JOINED is of type     DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `||` instead of the `+` sign to concatinate the date together.

```
UPDATE PARENT 
  SET RENEW_DATE = TO_DATE('08/31/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM JOINED), 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
WHERE STATUS_IND = 'Active'
```

Comment: "*concatenate the **date***" is not entirely correct. You are concatenating *strings* here, not dates. `'08/31/'` is character literal (aka "string") and the number returned by `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM JOINED)` will be implicitly converted to a string due to the way its used.

Comment: Ahh I see, so what if i need to add 1 to the year im getting here, or add 1 to the year of the result date I tried this
    `code` UPDATE PARENT 
    SET RENEW_DATE = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, TO_DATE('08/31/' || 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM JOINED) , 'MM/dd/yyyy'))
    WHERE STATUS_IND = 'Active' `code`

Comment: This results in ORA-00904: "DATEADD": invalid identifier

Comment: DATEADD is for SQL Server.  In Oracle, you can add days with a + or add an interval like "dateresult + interval '1' year.  In your example, you could also add 1 to the year before concatenating it to the rest of the date.

Comment: Sweet, much appreciated!